# How to use a for or while loop to filter a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

For a course at university where we learn how to do R, we have to filter a dataframe supplied (called crimes). The original dataframe has 8 columns.

I do not think I can supply the data set, since it is part of an assignment for school. But any advice would be really appreaciated.

The requirements of the tasks are to use a loop and an if-statement, to filter one column ("category") and take only the rows with one specific level (out of 14) (named "drugs"). Then printing only three out of the eight columns of those rows into a new dataframe.

```
for (i in crimes$category) {
  if (i == "drugs") {
    drugs <- rbind(drugs, crimes[c(2,3,7)]) 
  }
}
```

Now I know the problem is in the rbind function, since it now just duplicates all rows 160 times (there are 160 rows with the category "drugs". But I do not no how to get a dataframe with 160 observations and only 3 variables.

I do not think I can supply the data set, since it is part of an assignment for school. But any advice would be really appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the assignment defeats the purpose of using R.  But that said, use the `for` / `if` construct to get the row numbers containing the category value "drugs" then create the result df outside the loop:

```
keep <- integer()
for (i in crimes$category) {
  if (i == "drugs") {
    keep <- c(keep, i)
  }
}  

crimes2 <- crimes[keep, c(2,3,7)]
```

Note the base R no-loop solution would be:

```
crimes2 <- crimes[crimes$category == "drugs", c(2,3,7)]
```